# Show / Hide div based on Cookie Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I setup a form that people fill out. One of the form fields is a county dropdown.
The form action creates a cookie:

```
setcookie("county", $county, time() + 3600 /* one hour */, '/', 'subdomain.mydomain.com', false, false);
```

On the confirmation page I have multiple divs that are hidden by default:

```
<div id="county1">County 1 Content</div>
<div id="county2">County 2 Content</div>
<div id="county3">County 3 Content</div>
```

and so on...

Based on the county the user selects from the select drop down on the previous page I want the particular div to to display.

I tried:

```
<div style="visibility: hidden"><input id="county" name="county" value="<?php echo($_COOKIE['county']); ?>"></div>
```

and

```
$('#county').on('load', function () {
    if(this.value === "County1"){
        $("#county1").show();
    } else {
        $("#county1").hide();
    }
});
```

but input doesn't seem to support onLoad. Any suggestions?

Thanks!!

Comment: How does `setcookie` look like? What exactky does it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try `$( document ).ready()`

[JQuery documentaion](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

For example;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($.cookie('county') === "County1"){
        $("#county1").show();
    }else{
        $("#county1").hide();
    }
});
```

I'm using jquery cookie plugin:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie